# How do I get --value from document.getElementById("id").style?

Tags: html

```
<div id="progbar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="33" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value: 33"></div>
```

I need to get the "--value" here.

```
document.getElementById("progbar").style.value
document.getElementById("progbar").style.--value
```

I tried these but it didn't work, how can I get this value? Note: I'm working on Arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to retrieve it, is to use :

```
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("progbar"))
    .getPropertyValue('--value');
```

i found the solution here : https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript

you can also set the value :

```
document.getElementById("progbar").style
    .setProperty('--value', 'pink');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I try to throw a value by trying this "style" doesn't get any value.             <div id="progbar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="33" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style=""></div>

Comment: when i tried the second method i got this error:  (index):159 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementById')

Comment: i changed my answer i found a solution that works

Comment: After making some changes to my code the final solution worked. Thank you.